# SharePoint CSOM (C#) to get list of User alerts present in SharePoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, development, csom, alert

I want to use `microsoft.Sharepoint.client.dll` and `microsoft.Sharepoint.client.runtime.dll` to retrieve the list of user alerts.

Can any one please let me know how to retrieve the user alerts from sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
//load all users in the site collection
var siteUsersColl = from user in oWeb.SiteUsers
                where user.PrincipalType == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User
                select user;
var usersResult = context.LoadQuery(siteUsersColl);
context.ExecuteQuery();

int count = 0;
foreach (var user in siteUsersColl)
{
    //ensure that user is present
    var curruser = oWeb.EnsureUser(user.LoginName);

    //load the users alerts, available after jan 2017 CSOM update in SPO, not sure about OnPrem
    var alerts = user.Alerts;
    context.Load(alerts);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (Alert alert in alerts)
    {
        //get the alert
        var type = alert.Title;
    }

    count += alerts.Count;
}
```

Reference - [CSOM January 2017 update](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-january-2017)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I succeeded 50 % how bout retrieving the list name as it is giving property not initialized exception. if i access like `alert.List.Title`

Comment: Try it as below:

`                    foreach (Alert alert in alerts)
                    {
                        //get the alert
                        var type = alert.Title;
                        context.Load(alert.List,a => a.Title);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();

                        var listTitle = alert.List.Title;
                    }`

you need to load the list object and then execute the query

Comment: i tired with this but giving null reference exception.. :(